# In the svg file i need to extract class, cy and cx data from ellipse tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My svg file =

```
    <svg id="svgDoc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
             xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <script type="text/javascript" xlink:href="../include/SVGPan.js"/>
            <g id="viewport">
                <image height="3300" id="svgImage" preserveAspectRatio="none"
                       width="5100" xlink:href="ghun.png"/>
                <g class="hotspotborder">
                    <ellipse class="32" cx="3050" cy="269" fill="#FFFFFF"
                             fill-opacity="0.2" id="_32" name="32"
                             onclick="window.parent.highlight2dNode(this.id)"
                             ontouchend="window.parent.highlight2dNode(this.id)" rx="33"
                             ry="33"/>
      </g>
      </g>
      </svg>
```

My code:

```
if filename.endswith(".svg"):
    with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as f:
        for line in f:
            f = BeautifulSoup(line, 'lxml')
            for hit in f.findAll("ellipse", {"class","cy","cx"}):
                hit = hit.text.strip()
                print(hit)
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @DYZ In the above svg file i need to extract class, cy and cx data from ellipse tag.

Answer (score 1):

Read the entire file and set contents to svg = your xml. The following gives you the values.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(svg, 'lxml')
soup.find('ellipse')['cx']
soup.find('ellipse')['cy']
```

or you might change part of your code to this

```
for hit in f.find_all("ellipse"):
    print(hit['cx'])
    print(hit['cy'])
```